# How can I pre-select options in a multiple enabled v-select component?

Tags: vuetify.js, v-select

I have a v-select component, to allow user select from the combo "multiples" options.

```
            <v-select
              dense
              :items="merchants"
              item-text="name"
              item-value="id"
              name="merchants"
              v-model="editedItem.merchants"
              return-object
            >
            </v-select>
```

items is a list of objects, and the v-select is populated correctly.
v-model is an array of objects returned by an api.

as show in this capture:

[image: merchants array]

but when the v-select is open, no items are "allready" selected.

How is the data type that should be in v-model, to let v-select "match" items in the list with the one selected.

Thanks

and best regards

Comment: Can you provide an online demo/fiddle illustrating your scenario?

Comment: Hi @MajedBadawi give me a few hours!

Answer (score 1):

Just specify your API `merchants` data in `v-model` and all of those objects will be selected. And don't forget to add `item-text` and `item-value` props.

### Demo

https://codepen.io/aQW5z9fe/pen/JjYmoVb

```html
<v-select
  v-model="selected"
  :items="items"
  item-text="name"
  item-value="id"
  label="Select"
  multiple
></v-select>
```

```js
data () {
  return {
    items: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: 'merchant-1'
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'merchant-2'
      }
    ]
  } 
},
computed: {
  APIdata () {
    const merchants = [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: 'merchant-1'
      }
    ]
    return merchants
  }
}
```